# A linear algebra problem on eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are two linear maps from $V$ to $V$. let $v$ be an non-zero eigen vector corresponding to some eigen value $\lambda$ of $TS$. If $S(v)=0$ then $\lambda =0$. So, TS has only zero eigen value. Is it also true that ST also has zero eigen value under the condition that $S(v)=0$?

Comment: if $T(v)=v$ it certainly is the case since $ST(v)=S(T(v))=S(v)=0$

Comment: If $TS$ has a zero eigenvalue does not generally mean that $ST$ has one as well. All you can say is that $TS$ and $ST$ have the same *nonzero part* of their spectrum.

Comment: If $S(v)=0$ then $S$ has non-trivial kernel. So, $S$ is not one-one. So $ST$ is not one-one and so it has non-trivial kernel which implies $ST$ has zero eigen value.

Comment: You mean if $S(v)=0$ for some $v$ then $ST$ has a non-trivial kernel? Not necessarily if $\mathrm{Im}(T)\cap\mathrm{Ker}(S)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the answer is yes, because $\operatorname{rank} ST = \operatorname{rank} TS$ and your operators go from $V$ to $V$ (i.e., their matrix representations are square matrices). However, an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ need not be the same for $ST$ and $TS$.

By the way, *eigenvalue* and *eigenvector* are written as single words.